# How to make a request call running in the background in JS?

Tags: javascript, axios, promise

I have the following code:

```
function getRegionList() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const config: ExtendedAxiosConfig = {
            method: "GET",
            url: "businesses/regions",
            _addToken: false,
        };
        axios(config)
            .then((res) => {
                resolve(true);
                store.set(LocalStoragekeys.Regions, res.data.data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
    });
}
```

It returns about 10k rows (that will be stored in the indexDB) and takes about 20sec to be finished. I call it in the application's loading step and it's like a bottleneck and increases the bounce-rate.

Any idea how can I make it running in the background? I mean, avoid stopping for it to get finished.

Comment: [webworkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API?retiredLocale=de)?

Comment: It already is running in the background.

Comment: @Pointy well, it waits until the response get finished, then goes to the next page.

Comment: It doesn't. The `axios()` call is asynchronous. If it's taking a long time, the problem is with the server. Also there's no reason to wrap that in a Promise, as the axios call is already returning a Promise.

Comment: Ok @Pointy, yeah right, `axios()` is async. But if it is, so why it will be slow if the server response takes long time? If it's running in the background, then it should not be slow even if the server response takes 1 hour.

Comment: You can't expect the response to come "fast" on the client side when the server takes one hour to send it, or are the client and server in a different frame of reference that are relatively moving at near light speed?

Comment: *"avoid stopping for it to get finished"*: there is no code you have shared that is "stopping". The code you have shared allows for executing JavaScript while the response is not in yet. Maybe the code that *calls* `getRegionList` is only making a next call when the response of the previous call is in.

Comment: yes @trincot you got it .. the problem was the parent method, the one which is calling `getRegionList`, it's a `promises all` and waits until all request get their responses, then goes to the next step.